# Verify Truth Table: Switches and LED

Tags: digital-logic

I got a digital design problem.  My final implementation of the circuit program didn't achieve the required criteria, so I brought my problem and my works here to be suggested by you if I mis-manipulated any details.

**Logic System:**  Binary--1,0.

**Issue after Simulation and Test on Circuit Board:**  LED lighted up at the begining without any switches were turned ON. (Would it make sense?)

**Problem Statement:**

Use 4 switches A, B, C, D to control a LED.  LED is ON if the following conditions are satisfied,

D and B turn ON,

or A turns OFF while C turns ON,

or A and B turn ON and the rest turn OFF,

or C and D turn OFF,

or all switches turn ON.

**End of Problem Statement.**

Notations and Circuit Combinations we use:

**AND gate:**  · (dot)

**OR gate:**  +

**"Not/Invert something":**  ~

**SOP:** Sum of Products

**POS:** Product of Sums

SOP and POS are equivilant to each other.

**My works:**

True Table based on the 5 criteria

ON:1, OFF:0.

Collection of LED results is {1011111110001101}.

I can handle operating the software part, but I really want to check with you guys if I use POS method and based on the 5 criteria given in the problem, whether or not my true table is correct.

Please help me to point out my blind spots.  Thanks

Comment: how about instead of a delete you removed your answer from the question and post your answer with details of how you accomplished it to help future users.

Comment: @Kortuk Then I'd spare this question's life, if you think it deserves mercy.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the problem definition directly:

1. D and B turn ON: 
   B•D
2. A turns OFF while C turns ON: 
   ~A•C
3. A and B turn ON and the rest turn OFF:
   This condition is already covered by condition 4.
4. C and D turn OFF:
   ~C•~D
5. all switches turn ON:
   This condition is already covered by 1.

So your final function is:
B•D + ~A•C + ~C•~D

3 ands, 2 ors.

Comment: I tested my true table again without interchanging between 0&1 for the program and it was correct.  It also verified your statement that the 3rd condition is irrelevant because of condition 4, and I finally understand why you concluded that.  I think what messed me up previously was that I changed 1 for 0 and vice versus in my program so that absurdity occurred. Thanks.